# MySQL allowing INSERT with no valid

Tags: mysql

I know this must be a ridiculous question but i just cannot understand why this is happenning (getting started with MySQL). Basically i have these two tables:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `hospital`.`hospital`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `hospital`.`hospital` (
  `hospital_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hospital_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `hospital_address` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `hospital_phone1` VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
  `hospital_phone2` VARCHAR(11) NULL,
  `CRM_director` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`hospital_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `hospital_id_UNIQUE` (`hospital_id` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `hospital`.`employee`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `hospital`.`employee` (
  `employee_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `employee_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `funcao` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `shift` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `salary` INT NOT NULL,
  `hospital_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`employee_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `employee_id_UNIQUE` (`employee_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_employee_hospital_idx` (`hospital_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_employee_hospital`
    FOREIGN KEY (`hospital_id`)
    REFERENCES `hospital`.`hospital` (`hospital_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

The behaviour i would like to see when implementing the database is so that when i insert a new employee it won't allow the field hospital_id from this employee to be a non-existing id from the hospital table. However, i tried inserting a new employee specifying a non-existing hospital_id from my hospital table but mysql just allowed the insertion. The answer to this question will probably help me finish the whole project i am working on.

Comment: Your code looks okay.  The unique index on the primary keys are unnecessary.

Comment: Are you certain that a record for that hospital really didn't exist?

Comment: Example:

INSERT INTO `hospital`.`employee` (`employee_name`, `funcao`, `shift`, `salary`, `hospital_id`) VALUES ('bigfool', 'Janitor', '1', '2000', '200');

Results in success. However:

SELECT * FROM hospital.hospital;

Results in the following data:

hospital_id  hospital_name  Address  hospital_phone1  hospital_phone2
1    Samaritano  R x   2387432 

which does not contains an hospital_id = 200

Comment: Loaded your table into mysql, tried to add an employee with fake hospital id and it was rejected because of the foreign key as expected.

Comment: @Rodrigo Are you sure, that the `Foreign Key` really exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have commented, nothing wrong with your tables. Creating them and trying the insert you have provided produces an error as expected. Which impliest that you have set [foreign_key_checks](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_foreign_key_checks) to off

> If set to 1 (the default), foreign key constraints for InnoDB tables
>   are checked. If set to 0, foreign key constraints are ignored, with a
>   couple of exceptions.

If this is defined in your mysql configuration to be 0 or if you do

```
SET foreign_key_checks=0;
```

followed by

```
INSERT INTO employee (employee_name, funcao, shift, salary, hospital_id) VALUES ('bigfool', 'Janitor', '1', '2000', '200');
```

The insert will succeed.

Comment: Jesus...wasn't aware of that. I think i would never find it if not your tip haha. Thanks man... (feel embarrassed). At least it seems that i am doing everything else fine:)

Comment: Glad to have been of help